# glGenerateMipmap IMGSRV error

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, mipmaps

In my app I am trying to use textures but I am getting the errors

```
:0: SGXQueueTransfer: all paths failed
:0: HardwareMipGen: Failed to generate texture mipmap levels (error=3)
```

on my Galaxy Nexus. I don't get these errors on my EVO 4G.

Here is the relevant loading code.

```
private static int load(Context context, int resID) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            resID);

    int[] texts = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texts, 0);
    int texID = texts[0];

    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

    return texID;
}

private static int loadWithMipmap(Context context, int resID) {
    int texID = load(context, resID);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    return texID;
}
```

Any ideas what is going on and how I can fix it?

EDIT: There is only one image causing the error and it is a 1024x2048 png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this, and it worked once I squashed the image to be square. OpenGL doesn't give an error.

Comment: It's been a while since I fixed this but I think this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Frickin' scary. Tested on a Galaxy Nexus 7.

You need to do the following:

```
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
    GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    this.context.checkError("GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER");
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
    GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
```

Strictly speaking, I guess GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST isn't a valid MAG_FILTER. Nexus 7 thinks so anyway. And it mipmaps beautifully with the change made.

Comment: I changed my program to use one large sprite sheet instead of many images and now I don't get the error even with GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST. It was only failing on one image that was 1024x2048 but now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, as I don't have any access to the hardware you're mentioning, but does the error occur with a texture that has *non power of two* dimensions ?

Comment: They are all power of two dimensions. They don't show up at all on some phones if they're not. The dimensions of the one causing problems are 1024x2048